# How to track which image from the array the user clicked on and open it full screen (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I am learning and trying to write an analogue of the VKontakte application (facebook, if you understand it this way), I have a news feed that has an array of images and I need to somehow track which picture the user has clicked on and transfer this image or its address to the next screen but I can't figure out how to do it. attempts to put a tag on indexPath.row end up with the fact that first you have tag this is the total number of lines, and then the line that I rewound to
P.S.
Sorry for bad English, I had to do it through a translator

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy in my opinion. Every `UIImageView` has a property called `image` which will give you the optional `UIImage`. Attach a gesture recognizer to the image view and in the handler function, extract the `image` property from the sender's view(i.e the UIImageView instance in your case) and transfer it to the next view controller in any way you prefer. If you don't know how to do it in code, I recommend you to learn the gesture recognizers and handling user events first. I think it's very straightforward.

Comment: I'm add gesture recognizer, but how to use or write  indexPath of imageView, that im clicked? in other cases I can use didSelectedRow at indexpath, but in this case this method didn't work

Comment: If you're using the collection view, you don't need to add a gesture recognizer. Your cell might store the image view property. Inside your cell, override `isSelected` variable and track `didSet` property observer. Once isSelected is true, you can extract the image from your image view and pass it to the another view controller.

Comment: if I understand correctly - no, this is not a CollectionView, its TableView, which xib Cell have stack of ImageView, which outlets united into the UIImageView array

Comment: UITableView also has isSelected. If you're adding multiple images inside your cell and you need to know which image is selected, then, you need some trick inside your cell class like adding tap gesture recognizer to each image and also make sure isUserInteractionEnabled set to true.